# Magento 2. Product not visible on frontend in category view

Tags: magento2, product, frontend

Products have all the correct settings (setting, visibility, stock, category assignment, etc).  . (The are visible if I enter the product url directly).

There are no products under category view or in any product listings (I have a widget that uses it).

The only difference between local(where products are visible) and remote 
is that the media folder has 777 permissions on local and 775 on remote.

Could the permissions one the media folder affect the visibility of the products or am I barking the wrong tree?

EDIT
 - Single store view.
 - Reindexed

Comment: Can you check if in the **Store View** the configs are the same as in the **Website** ?

Comment: Did you try reindexing?